# css compressor and factorization

Tags: css, optimization

I'm working with a friend on a project with a huge CSS file.
There is a lot of duplication like:

```
h1 {
  color : black;
}

h1 {
  color : blue;
  width: 30px;
}
```

The first `h1` can be removed, because it will never be used, because fully rewrited by the second. (because it is in the same CSS file)

I would know if it exists a tool that factorizes (and compress) this kind of stuff.
To only have at the end:

```
h1 {color:blue;width:30px}
```

PS: If it can be an online tool, it will be perfect!

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice one in ruby: http://zmoazeni.github.io/csscss

In node.js: https://github.com/rbtech/css-purge

Both are very easy to use from command line.

This is also a nice once: http://cssmerge.sourceforge.net

And a plugin for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/css-usage

Comment: We have just launched our update, which does its job better, faster and even more now :) ~  http://rbtech.github.io/css-purge

Answer (score 2):

First you can try

- [CSS usage checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/css-usage/)

Then Try these

- [CSS Compressor](http://www.csscompressor.com/)
- [Javascript Compressor](http://jscompress.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firefox, you can use this addon which will help you achieve it.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/css-usage/

It creates a new css which tells you only used rules and sideline unused one. It also lets you export that css.